# Pivoting a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got  this question in a recent interview. My SQL is rusty and I don't even know where to begin.

Here's a provided table

```
-----------------------------------
date      product     quantity_sold
-----------------------------------
12/3/2019    A           200
-----------------------------------
11/6/2019    B           200
-----------------------------------
12/7/2019    B           200
-----------------------------------
10/1/2019    C           200
-----------------------------------
12/9/2019    D           200
-----------------------------------
```

If there are only 3 products A, B and C display the data in the following format

```
date product_A_quantity_sold  product_A_quantity_sold  product_A_quantity_sold
```

Answer (score 1):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
select date,
  max(case when product = 'A' then quantity_sold end) product_A_quantity_sold,
  max(case when product = 'B' then quantity_sold end) product_B_quantity_sold,
  max(case when product = 'C' then quantity_sold end) product_C_quantity_sold
from tablename
group by date
```

If you want to see `0` instead of `NULL` when a product is not sold for a date, then add to each of the `CASE` expressions an `ELSE` part, like:

```
max(case when product = 'A' then quantity_sold else 0 end) product_A_quantity_sold
```

For MySql, you could also use this code:

```
select date,
  max((product = 'A') * quantity_sold) product_A_quantity_sold,
  max((product = 'B') * quantity_sold) product_B_quantity_sold,
  max((product = 'C') * quantity_sold) product_C_quantity_sold
from tablename
group by date
```

Comment: Why the max and the multiplier?

Comment: MAX() is just a way to aggregate (it's just common practice to use MAX, although in your case it could be MIN, or SUM). In the 2nd query I use one of Mysql features which is to return 0 or 1 for False or True for Boolean expressions like `product = 'A'`. So the multiplication `(product = 'A') * quantity_sold` returns either `0` (if product <> 'A') or `quantity_sold` (if product = 'A').